# Can't seem to do a simple execute of PowerShell script from asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I don't have much experience with PowerShell but I'm trying to execute a script from my ASP.NET application and I'm not having much luck.

```
//Initialize PowerShell engine
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddScript("C:\\ps scripts\\Set-SSPortalAL1.ps1 sibtest"); `

// Execute the script
var results = shell.Invoke();
```

I don't get any error back, and I can see in PowerShell that the script does not get executed. Also, if I put a scriptname that doesn't exist, I get the same result.

Can anyone assist on how I can troubleshoot this further?  The script itself does not output anything after it is executed.

Thanks!

EDIT:  I tried running this code to check for errors

```
if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
                             {
                                 foreach (ErrorRecord er in errors)
                                 {
                                     Console.WriteLine(er.Exception.ToString());
                                 }
                             }
```

At first I got an error

> The term 'C:\ps' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Which means it was stumbling on the space in the folder name.  So I updated my path with single quotes as follows

```
shell.Commands.AddScript("'C:\\ps scripts\\Set-SSPortalAL1.ps1 sibtest'");
```

The errors now go away, but the code does not get executed.  Also, if I change the script to something that doesn't exist like Set-SSFDFDAFDFD.ps1 I still don't get any errors

Comment: How do you know it didnt run?

Comment: The script changes a field for an AD user. When I run it manually from PowerShell it functions as expected.

Comment: Well you might be getting a access denied in the Powershell. 
Put a try catch in your powershell and output any error to a file.
Is there any output?

Comment: What does `shell.HadErrors` say?

Comment: Updated the main post and added some error checking code

Comment: Script filename is **not** script, but command.

Comment: Not sure what you mean @PetSerAl can you elaborate?

Comment: `.AddCommand(@"C:\ps scripts\Set-SSPortalAL1.ps1").AddArgument("sibtest")`

Answer (score 1):

AddScript is a bit poorly named; the string you provide is run as a PowerShell *command*, not necessarily a script. In PowerShell, if you provide the name of a script file as a command, PowerShell will execute it. That's what the examples for AddScript do -- but `AddScript("Get-Process")` will work just as well.

The problem you're having is the single quotes - by surrounding the path to your script file with single quotes, you're providing PowerShell with just a string. So all your code is doing is echoing the script filepath to the "Console" - it's not every trying to invoke the script. That's why you get the same behavior when you specify a file that doesn't exist.

You can try moving the script to a path with no spaces and removing the single quotes, or you can use PowerShell's call operator (&) to tell it that you want to run the string as a command, like so:

```
shell.Commands.AddScript("& 'C:\\ps scripts\\Set-SSPortalAL1.ps1' sibtest");
```

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty simple use the following code - I also like to execute the PS1 file from a Batch File as well which allows you to port the task over to a windows scheduled task if you wanted.

```
 var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FilePath, ParametersForPowershell)
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true
            };

            using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
            {
                if (process != null)
                {
                    process.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                           Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
                           //Write To External Log if necessary
                        }
                    };
                    process.BeginOutputReadLine();

                    process.ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"ERROR: {e.Data}");
                            //Write To External Log if Necessary
                        }
                    };
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                    process.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
```

Contents of Batch File (ExecutePowershell.bat)

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File "%1"
```

Comment: Obviously your answer is not simple at all! And you should use PowerShell from System.Management.Automation assembly, as by https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/